# How to remove enum from string?

Tags: c#, string, enums, substring, suffix

I have a set of enum values and an input string, and in case the string has a suffix which is one of the enum names, I want to delete it.

For example, let's say I have

```
enum colors { red, blue, green, white }
```

And I receive the input string "`str = evergreen`", I want to do something like

```
if (str.endsWith(colors)) {
   output = str.trimSuffix(colors)
}
```

and get the string `ever` in `output`. Modifying str itself instead of saving it to a new variable is also fine.

is there a simple and/or elegant way to do it without hard coding the enum as array of strings and iterate over it?

Comment: You can use `Enum.GetValues(typeof(colors))` to avoid having to hard code them.

Comment: ```Enum.GetValues(typeof(colors))``` just should just get the appropriate integer values, you should use ```Enum.GetNames(typeof(colors))``` instead

Comment: where is trimSuffix defined?

Comment: Thanks!
Then now I only need to understand how to remove the suffix if it's an array element, I think that finding this solution might be simpler

Comment: @BernardVanderBeken, it's not, its a kind of pseudo-code. I'm trying to find something that has the functionality of trimSuffix - take str and trim its suffix if the suffix is one of the names in colors

Answer (score 2):

This code will remove any suffix from `str` that is defined in the `enum` below

```
var values = Enum.GetNames(typeof(colors));
var str = "evergreen";

var suffix = values.OrderByDescending(v => v.Length)
    .FirstOrDefault(v => str.EndsWith(v));

if(suffix != null)
{
    str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - suffix.Length);
}

enum colors { 
   red,
   blue,
   green,
   white 
}
```

Comment: Seems fine, as long as no enum values are part of another one. Maybe best to sort the enum names by length to work around this?

Comment: Added `.OrderByDescending(v => v.Length)` so that we will use the longest matching enum value